# How to test send message in kafka with jest?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, kafkajs

```
export const produce = async (topic: string, url: string): Promise<void> => {
   await producer.connect();
   await producer.send({
      topic,
      compression: CompressionTypes.GZIP,
      messages: [{ key: `key-${Math.random() * 100000}`, value: url }],
   });

   await producer.disconnect();
};
```

I have a send message kafka like this how can I test this function with `jest`, because that if we want to run jest we must run service `Kafka` and `zookeeper`. what could I do ?

I had try something like :

```
describe("Helper kafka", () => {
   describe("produce", () => {
      it("Pass 1 url should return 1", () => {
         expect(produce("testing", "URL")).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
   });
});
```

It's failed because the service is not running.

Comment: You need to mock your services. This may help: https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions

Comment: yes, I knew but I don't know how to apply that. Could you help me?

Comment: kafkajs project itself uses Docker containers to start temporary brokers rather than mocks